# How can I implement an IPv6 translation layer in userspace?

Tags: linux, sockets, networking, ipv6

I have a program in userspace with thousands of "nodes". Each of these nodes has a MAC address and can produce and consume messages. I would like to grant each of these nodes an IPv6 address and translate the messages to UDP payloads.

By "translate" I mean that a node can register to send messages to a destination IP address, and then when it produces a message I would like to translate this to a UDP payload to send to that destination with the node's IP address as the source address. And when a UDP packet is received with the node's IP address as the destination address, I would like to translate this to a message that the node can consume.

This is similar to what 6lowpan does (it provides an IPv6 translation layer for 802.15.4 nodes), but I would like to do it in userspace. 6lowpan is implemented in the kernel.

One way I can do this is to open a `tun` device, which would allow me to send raw IPv6 packets. But this means I would need to duplicate the IPv6 and UDP stacks in my program. For example, my program would be responsible for handling ICMP messages, implementing duplicate address detection, UDP checksums, etc.

Is there an easier way to do this? What I'd like to do is request a globally addressable IPv6 address from the kernel for each node and then use the typical socket method for sending and receiving UDP.

I would like to target linux, but I could use a BSD as well.

Comment: I think you are confused. 6LoWPAN doesn't have a translation mechanism; there is a network stack, just like with any other host. Network stacks are implemented in the OS kernel. You could implement one in user space, but it is still a network stack. UDP datagrams would be encapsulated by IPv6 packets, which would be encapsulated in frames of some layer-2 protocol. You claim to use MAC addresses, so the layer-2 protocol would be some IEEE LAN protocol, e.g. 802.3 (ethernet), 802.11 (Wi-Fi), etc.

Comment: It looks like you're correct. I don't know where I got the idea that 6lowpan does a translation. So 6lowpan nodes are the ones forming the IPv6 and UDP packets. Is there anything wrong with doing a translation layer to avoid putting that burden on the end-node and to reduce overhead? I thought there was precedent with 6lowpan, but now I don't know of an example of a translation layer.

Comment: Translation doesn't make much sense. The different network layers encapsulate, not translate, each other. Higher layers, e.g. UDP at layer-4, are encapsulated by lower layers, e.g. IPv6 at layer-3. Any network translations happen in the same network layer, e.g. NAT translates layer-3 addresses. The layers serve different purposes, so there really isn't any translating between the layers.

Comment: Translation could make sense if you don't need the full power of the layer. For example, the IP and UDP layers allow you to specify the destination address and port with each message. What if you only wanted to talk to one destination address and port, only ever wanted to use UDP, and you wanted to avoid specifying this information each time (for bandwidth reasons). Then you could send just the payload over the low-bandwidth point-to-point link, and the other side of the link could translate to proper IP/UDP and send over the internet.

Comment: No, translation between layers doesn't make sense because each layer performs different functions. For example, UDP doesn't have any facility for the fields in an IP header, and those fields are used for different purposes than UDP uses. It sounds like you really want to create your own protocol that only has addresses in the protocol header.

Comment: I'm not talking about translation between layers. Indeed, I am creating my own point-to-point protocol, and I want to know how I can make the node on the other end of the point-to-point protocol addressable via IPv6 without encapsulating the IP packets (to avoid the overhead and to leverage as much of the linux IP stack as possible).

Comment: You are really going to need to replace both IP and UDP with your own protocol(s). You could leverage the layer-1/2 (ethernet) part of the Linux network stack, but IPv6 in the Linux network stack is IPv6, with all its baggage. UDP has very little baggage, but it requires IP, so it inherits the IPv6 baggage.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131257/discussion-between-awelkie-and-ron-maupin).